# How can I get my bigrams to actually print? I get an error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I am trying to print the bigrams for a text in Python 3.5. The text is already pre-processed and split into individual words.

I tried two different ways (shown below), neither work.

The first:

```
ninety_seven=df.loc[97]
nine_bi=ngrams(ninety_seven,2)
print(nine_bi)
```

This outputs:

```
< generator object ngrams at 0x0B4F9E70>
```

The second is:

```
ninety_seven=df.loc[97]
bigrm = list(nltk.bigrams(ninety_seven))
print(*map(' '.join, bigrm), sep=', ')
```

This outputs:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

`df.loc[97]` is `[car, chip, indication, posted, flight, post, flight]`

I want it to print as:

```
car chip, chip indication, indication posted, posted flight, flight post, post flight
```

Comment: Try this `print(" ".join(ninety_seven))`... it will work Insha'Allah

Comment: @Anwarvic That doesn't call `ngrams`

Comment: Sorry, I mean `print(" ".join(nine_bi))`

Comment: @Anwarvic that gives me the following error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> ninety_seven=df.loc[97].loc['FSR Narrative']
>>> nine_bi=ngrams(ninety_seven,2)
>>> print(nine_bi)
<generator object ngrams at 0x7f879020f308>
>>> print([" ".join(t) for t in nine_bi])
['car chip', 'chip indication', 'indication posted', 'posted flight', 'flight post', 'post flight']
```

Here is a simple example:

```
>>> from nltk import ngrams

>>> test = ['car', 'chip', 'indication', 'posted', 'flight', 'post', 'flight']
>>> nine_bi=ngrams(test,2)
>>> print(nine_bi)
<generator object ngrams at 0x7f879020f308>
>>> print([" ".join(t) for t in nine_bi])
['car chip', 'chip indication', 'indication posted', 'posted flight', 'flight post', 'post flight']
```

Comment: for some reason I keep getting the same error:TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: Could you try the attached simple example?

Comment: The simple example works, but I have an excel sheet with ~2000 texts and am trying to get the bigrams to display for one of the texts by calling df.loc[97]

Comment: Could you post the exact output from `df.loc[97]`?

Comment: what are the keys of `df`? use `df.keys()`

Comment: use `df.keys()` not `df.keys`

Comment: sorry it gives: Index(['FSR Narrative', 'Mode'], dtype='object')

Comment: `FSR Narrative` is a class that you use, what are its member variables?

Comment: FSR narrative is the excel sheet, I have about 2000 rows of different texts in that sheet. does that answer your question?